# Edit button in Tkinter message-box

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using Tkinter to make GUI. I included a messagebox in my code, here's the detail:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *
root=Tk()

askyesno(message="Are you sure you want to choose this text file?")
```

When the askyesno pops up, there are 2 buttons: Yes and No, but I want to customize these buttons to "OK" and "Cancel", for example. I have been looking for how to customize Tkinter messagebox buttons many times but I found nothing. Any help? Thanks

Comment: You already have an answer, but just a suggestion: Avoid importing everything from a module. It can cause hard debugging issues. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `messagebox.askokcancel`

```
from tkinter import Tk,Button,messagebox
root=Tk()
def create_message():
    messagebox.askokcancel("Title",'Hello')

b=Button(root,text='Message',command=create_message)
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I mean that's an example, I want another text, not OK and Cancel

Comment: @Nomore [here](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/tkMessageBox.html) is a list of all the available functions in that module (maybe there is more), if none of those satisfy your needs, you will need to create a custom dialog box using `Toplevel` class (because there should be only one `Tk` instance), then you can customize everything about it

Comment: @Matiiss Yeah but this messagebox is beautiful and I like them. However, thank you for your help!

Comment: @Nomore Check the source code of [```messagebox```](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/tkinter/messagebox.py)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import messagebox
  
root = Tk()

button=Button("Message",)
messagebox.askokcancel()
```